# If $ a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}$ and $c$ is even, prove that $a$ and $b$ are both even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility, parity

Question:

If $ a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}$ and $c$ is even, prove that $a$ and $b$ are both even.

I am not quite sure how to prove this. My guess is proof by contradiction.
Assume the contrary, that is, $a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}$ for $c$ even and at least one of $a,b$ odd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$c$ is even, thus $c^2=4n$ for some integer $n$.

Now if $a,b$ are both odd, then

$$a^2+b^2=(2k+1)^2 + (2m +1)^2$$
$$=4k^2+ 4k + 1 + 4m^2 + 4m+ 1$$
$$=4n' + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod4$$

Thus $4 \nmid (a^2+b^2)$, while $4 \mid c^2$ - contradiction.

Also it is obvious that if $a$ even and $b$ odd, or $a$ odd and $b$ even; then $a^2+b^2$ is odd, while $c^2$ is even - contradiction.

Thus it has to be that both $a$, $b$ are even.

Comment: on your last second line, If both are $(a,b)$ odd then also $a^2+b^2=$ even.

Comment: So basically we choose one of the cases,(1) $a,b$ odd, (2) $a$ odd $b$ even, (3) $a$ even $b$ odd and show that there is a contradiction right?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Right, you get it. For each case, we showed the contradiction

Comment: @mathlover I think your statement is correct, but does not help with the proof. Thus instead of showing $a^2+b^2$=even, I showed $4$ does not divide $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: @YujieZha what does $|$ represent?

Comment: @TheGamer It means "divides", so for integers $a,b,c$, if $ab=c$, we say $a$ or $b$ divides $c$, with the notation $a \mid c$

Comment: i dont get how u got $4n' +2 =2$ (mod 4) from?

Comment: @TheGamer So from the equation just above this, you get $4(k^2+m^2+k+m)+2$, and let $n'=k^2+m^2+k+m$

Comment: @YujieZha $4 \nmid (a^2+b^2)$ because of the 2 there?

Comment: @TheGamer Right, we need it to be 0 in order to say $4 \mid (a^2+b^2)$

Comment: @YujieZha sorry to disturb u can u make $c^2 =2n$ or does it have to be 4n

Comment: @TheGamer No worries. Notice $a^2+b^2$ is also even, and thus if you make it $c^2=2n$, you would not arrive at contradictions.

Answer (score 0):

Since $c$ is even then $c=2k$ for some $k$. Now, suppose $a$ is odd, then $a=2m + 1$ therefore: $4m^2 + 4m + 1 +b^2 = 4k^2$. It follows $4 | 1 + b^2$ therefore $b$ is odd, $b=2n+1$ and $4 | 2 + 4n + 4n^2$, impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and $c$ is even. Since  $a^2=c^2-b^2=(c+b)(c-b)$, $a$ and $b$ have the same parity. Assume $a$ is odd. Then $a^2+b^2\equiv 2(\mod4)$, whence $c^2\equiv2(\mod 4)$ which is a contradiction since $4\mid c^2$ as $2\mid c$. Hence $a$ and $b$ are even.

Answer (score 0):

Obviuosly:
$$odd + even \ne even,$$
$$even + odd \ne even$$
Assume both odd:
$$(2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2=(2k)^2 \Rightarrow$$
$$((2m+1)+(2n+1))^2=(2k)^2+2(2m+1)(2n+1) \Rightarrow$$
$$4(m+n+1)^2=4k^2+2(2m+1)(2n+1).$$
The last term is not divisible by $4$, hence contradiction. Both must be even.